# Rendering in Dreamweaver different than live site

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser, dreamweaver

I am responsible for a site that needs to work in IE 9 as well as current browsers. The site is http://www.wtc.army.mil/  I have made some changes to the current live site and need to push them live, however when I render inside DW in IE 9, a few minor elements on the page will not render properly even though I haven't changed these sections of the code (these elements being: social media icons at top right of page will not display, the glyphicons (i think that's what they're called) next to some of links at the bottom won't display, and one other image next to a paragraph on the right side of the page).

I have compared the new code to the current live site and there are no differences within the code besides the minor changes that should not affect the failed elements I mentioned. The changes I have made should in no way affect these elements that are not displaying properly. Could DW be rendering the page differently then how it will show when I push it live, and these elements that aren't rendering correctly in DW actually be fine when I push them live? Another thing to note is that the new code works perfect in other browsers. its IE that is causing the issue. So my main question is: Is it possible for DW to render the code in IE differently then how it appears when it is pushed live?

Comment: You could try to access your site through local address in IE9 and look if those elements are displayed correctly, besides that Dreamweaver isn't the best piece of software for professional web-development.

Answer (score 1):

Dreamweaver has always had this issue. This is why most webdevelopers do not use a program like Dreamweaver, simply because it is not a browser and its Design View cannot render like one. This is totally not your fault, but dreamweaver's.

My best guess would be to have some IE specific css to fix the difference in the browsers.

```
@media screen\0 {
    /*CSS here applies to IE 8, 9 and 10*/
}

@media screen\9 {
    /*CSS here applies to IE 6 and 7*/
}
```

Or if that doesn't work, add a stylesheet to your HTML head that has IE only CSS:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```